# Create minutely date_time range using Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to create a time range with a sample every 2.5 minutes, where I know the start time and number of samples.

Here is code to get 1000 timestamps separated by 5 minutes starting from a given day:

```
date = pandas.date_range(datetime(2015, 12, 25, hour=12, minute=0),
                         periods=1000, freq='5min')
```

How can I specify a 2 min 30 sec frequency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `2min30S` as the `freq` param:

```
In [9]:
pandas.date_range(datetime(2015, 12, 25, hour=12, minute=0), periods=1000, freq='2min30S')
Out[9]:
DatetimeIndex(['2015-12-25 12:00:00', '2015-12-25 12:02:30',
               '2015-12-25 12:05:00', '2015-12-25 12:07:30',
               '2015-12-25 12:10:00', '2015-12-25 12:12:30',
               '2015-12-25 12:15:00', '2015-12-25 12:17:30',
               '2015-12-25 12:20:00', '2015-12-25 12:22:30',
               ...
               '2015-12-27 05:15:00', '2015-12-27 05:17:30',
               '2015-12-27 05:20:00', '2015-12-27 05:22:30',
               '2015-12-27 05:25:00', '2015-12-27 05:27:30',
               '2015-12-27 05:30:00', '2015-12-27 05:32:30',
               '2015-12-27 05:35:00', '2015-12-27 05:37:30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1000, freq='150S')
```

Or `150S` will also work